# Почему глаголы создать и есть спрягаются иным методом?

Tags: этимология

Мне просто интересно, откуда так произошло, что эти глаголы спрягаются по-другому. Как их спрягать, я знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глаголы есть, дать, создать и быть (а также производные) имеют особые окончаниям личных формах, являющиеся архаическими: ем, ешь, ест, едим, едите, едят; дам, дашь, даст, дадим, дадите, дадут; создам, создашь, создаст, создадим, создадите, создадут. От глагола быть в современном русском языке сохранились редко употребительные формы настоящего времени - есть и суть, а будущее время образуется от другого корня: буду, будешь, будет, будем, будете, будут.

Подробнее - в таблице спряжений древнерусских глаголов:

http://tezaurus.oc3.ru/docs/1/articles/3/3/5/

Comment: Людмила, если я правильно понимаю, по Вашей ссылке какое-то отношение к заданному вопросу может иметь разве что табличка "Происхождение личных окончаний глаголов настоящего времени". В этот текст даже (мне с некоторым опытом и некоторым пониманием древнерусского) вникнуть непросто. Надо еще знать основы индоевропеистики.     
Боюсь, автор сочтет не совсем корректным отсылку к такому материалы. Впрочем, ответа на вопрос "ПОЧЕМУ" нет и там. ))))

Answer (score 1):

А. Глаголы в русском языке образуют сложную систему словоизменения, которая подробно изучается в общей грамматике. Это выглядит примерно так:

1) Все глаголы делятся на классы и группы. Классификация глаголов определяется двумя факторами: а) соотношение основ инфинитива и формы настоящего времени; б) понятие продуктивности, то есть способности данного класса глаголов служить образцом при создании новых слов.

2) Глаголы с продуктивным соотношением основ делятся на 5 классов, а непродуктивные глаголы с индивидуальным соотношением основ делятся на 10 групп. Каждый класс или группа относится к определенному спряжению – первому или второму.

3) Существует класс ИЗОЛИРОВАННЫХ глаголов, которые характеризуются особым соотношением основ или особыми системами окончаний:  бежать, хотеть, есть, надоесть, дать (создать и др.), быть (забыть, добыть и др.), ехать, идти.
Приведенная классификация глаголов не изучается в средней школе.

Б. Спряжение современного русского языка – результат упрощения более сложной системы спряжения древнерусского языка. По формам настоящего времени все глаголы древнерусского языка делились на пять классов - четыре ТЕМАТИЧЕСКИХ и один НЕТЕМАТИЧЕСКИЙ.

1-ый класс - глаголы характеризовались тематическим гласным [е], чередующимся с [о]: несеши – несёт.

2-ой класс - характеризовался тем же тематическим гласным [е], чередующимся с [о], но осложненным [н]: [не]/[но]: стать – станеши.

3-ий класс - имел также тематический гласный [е] в чередовании с [о], но осложненный предшествующим [j]: [je]/[jo]: знати – знаеши.

4-ый класс - имеет тематический гласный -и, в современном русском языке такие глаголы относятся ко второму спряжению (ходити, хвалити).

К нетематическим относилось всего пять глаголов: быти, дати, ести, ведети  и имети. 
В 1-м л. ед. ч. у этих глаголов было окончание |мь] (есмь, дамь, емь, вемь, имамь), во 2-м л,- [си] (ecu, даси, еcu, веси, но имаши); в остальных лицах окончания были те же, что и у тематических глаголов.
http://www.bibliofond.ru/view.aspx?id=560913

Answer (score 0):

Вы не могли бы уточнить, что Вы разумеете под "почему"? Если Вас интересует какая-то исчерпывающая причинно-следственная связь, то вряд ли она вообще возможна в вопросах лингвистики (кроме правописания), поскольку язык не создавался целенаправленно по чьей-то воле. 
И второе. Парадигма спряжения "создать" - производна от "дать". Так что тут ни о какой нестандартности и говорить не приходится.